# Getting ETimedOut error when trying to install packages using npm in windows

Tags: proxy, npm

I'm facing this "ETimedOut" error when trying to use this command "npm install -g yo" .Actually I'm using a network proxy to access internet.

I got a warning message that "If u are behind a proxy,please make sure that 'proxy' config is set properly ".
Can anyone please help me out regarding this issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot.I'm able to resolve my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the [npm proxy config parameter](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#proxy) using these commands:

```
npm config set proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
```

[Source](http://jjasonclark.com/how-to-setup-node-behind-web-proxy/)